# generating HDFS sequence files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I'm running pig script from Java using org.apache.pig.PigServer class.
I need to output my files in sequence format compressed in gz.
this is what I've done:

```
effectivePigProperties.put("mapred.output.compress", "true");
effectivePigProperties.put("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat");
effectivePigProperties.put("mapred.output.compression.type", "SequenceFile.CompressionType.BLOCK");
effectivePigProperties.put("mapred.output.compression.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec");
```

the output is in gz but not sequenced files.
what am i missing?

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423949/storing-data-to-sequencefile-from-apache-pig

Answer (score 0):

While not present in the Apache Pig bundle (nor its Piggybank) yet, Twitter's Elephant Bird library provides a [SequenceFileStorage implementation](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/pig/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/store/SequenceFileStorage.java) you can make use of.